# Pivot table dataframe output shows 2 columns, but pivot table .shape shows only 1 column (45, 1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble selecting the columns from my pivot table in order to create a bar chart from matplotlib package. Code below creates the pivot table from data in an excel file and also saves the table to its own excel file for each new day. The data in the pivot table is correct and I am happy with that, however I'm struggling to create a graph from the pivot table, as below:

```
import numpy as np
import os
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

require_cols = ['ship_id', 'hours_diff_last_ais_and_last_processed_grouped']
require_cols1 = ['ship_id', 'hours_since_last_processed', 'ship_status']
last_processed_data = "C:/Users/Michael Callum/trade_queue_last_processed_data.xlsx"
last_processed_data_csv = "C:/Users/Michael Callum/trade_queue_last_processed_data.csv"
new_last_processed_dir_name = "C:/Users/Michael Callum"
new_last_processed_base_file_name = "trade queue last processed "
today_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
new_last_processed_filename_suffix = ".xlsx"

new_last_processed_data_file = os.path.join(new_last_processed_dir_name, new_last_processed_base_file_name + today_date + new_last_processed_filename_suffix)

df = pd.read_excel(last_processed_data, sheet_name="Sheet1", usecols=require_cols)
print(df.columns)

HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable = pd.pivot_table(df, index=["hours_diff_last_ais_and_last_processed_grouped"], values=['ship_id'], aggfunc='count', fill_value='')


HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.to_excel(new_last_processed_data_file, sheet_name="Hours diff last AIS and Process")
print(HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable)
print(HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.columns)
print(HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.shape)

x = HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable["hours_diff_last_ais_and_last_processed_grouped"]
print(x)
```

Full output below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael Callum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2889, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
                                                ship_id
hours_diff_last_ais_and_last_processed_grouped         
-24                                                  61
-23                                                  34
-22                                                  50
-21                                                  51
-20                                                  61
-19                                                  48
-18                                                  59
-17                                                  61
-16                                                  83
-15                                                 108
-14                                                  86
-13                                                  79
-12                                                  75
-11                                                 110
-10                                                  83
-9                                                  117
-8                                                  135
-7                                                  149
-6                                                  160
-5                                                  182
-4                                                  182
-3                                                  206
-2                                                  287
-1                                                  308
0                                                   888
1                                                   911
2                                                  2030
3                                                  2087
4                                                  2149
5                                                  2063
6                                                  1929
7                                                  1817
8                                                  1682
9                                                  1643
10                                                 1744
11                                                 1743
12                                                 1443
13                                                 1010
108                                                   1
136                                                   1
162                                                   1
164                                                   2
191                                                   1
469                                                   1
<-24                                               8778
Index(['ship_id'], dtype='object')
(45, 1)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 97, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'hours_diff_last_ais_and_last_processed_grouped'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Michael Callum/MyPythonScripts/PivotTableGraph.py", line 30, in <module>
    x = HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable["hours_diff_last_ais_and_last_processed_grouped"]
  File "C:\Users\Michael Callum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2899, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\Michael Callum\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'hours_diff_last_ais_and_last_processed_grouped'
```

Comment: What does `df.columns` show?  Does 'hours_diff_last_ais_and_last_processed_grouped' appear in this out exactly?

Comment: Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, make sure you're comparing `HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.columns` with `HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.shape` once `df` is supposed to have more columns because such columns became an index in `HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable` by using `pd.pivot_table`.

Comment: df.columns shows: `Index(['ship_id', 'hours_diff_last_ais_and_last_processed_grouped'], dtype='object')` @ScottBoston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by the output, but it appears that the column that you're trying to call, `hours_diff_last_ais_and_last_processed_grouped` is index. You can either reset the index, df.reset_index() (returns a DataFrame, recommended) and use it as a column or use `x = HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.index`.

Comment: Thanks, `x = HoursDiffLastAisProcessPivotTable.index ` does exactly what I wanted